# Modifying a .reg file with returned variables from a VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, registry

I am trying to: 1 Discover the user that is logged into the machine, add it to variable 1.
Then find out the SID in HKEY_USERS for this said user, add it to variable 2.
Once i have the SID, pipe it into a .reg file replacing the values that i have in it.
Code 1 finds the user. the result then goes into the code 2 replacing "Myusername" This finds the SID.

I then need to send this to a .reg file i made to replace certain registry paths.

Am i on the right track? Or way off? can anyone make these 2 peices of code work together?

Thanks guys. Any help is appreciated.

So far i have:
Code 1:

```
        Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Wscript.Echo "The current user is " & objNetwork.UserName
```

and
Code 2:

```
    strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set objAccount = objWMIService.Get _
("Win32_UserAccount.Name='Myusername',Domain='gnb'")
Wscript.Echo objAccount.SID
```

Comment: What do you ultimately want to achieve with this .reg file? What does the file look like and what is the type of the value you need to create? Have you at least tried to merge the 2 code snippets you have?

Comment: Well i'm no pro at this, and i am trying to solve a problem where i need to add a bunch of trusted sites to the currently logged in user's SID folder in the registry. this is because of the way this network is set up. Some users land in HKLU as it should, but others land in HKU instead in those randomly generated SID filders that start with S-1-x-x...

Comment: I have tried to combine my 2 codes, but becaus eof my lack of knowledge in VBS, im not quite sure how.

Comment: Mabe i should be looking into using something like a .bat file or powershell...